# Vuejs Laravel always returns validation messages in English despite language switched to 'fr'

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-9

In my SPA the register form works correctly and displays the validation error messages in English.
To get them in an other language, I previously switch the laravel app 's language by mean of a controller that does the following.

```php
public function index(Request $request){
  App::setLocale($request->lang);

  session()->put('locale', $request->lang);
  return response()->json([App::getLocale(),session()->get('locale')]);
}
```

The returned response is correct

> ["fr","fr"]

Thus, I am authorized to think that the Laravel app has its language set to French.

In the `lang` folder, I made a copy of all the stuff under `en` into a `fr` folder. Then I translated some of the messages that appear as error when I enter bad values. Unfortunately the messages still appear in English!?

What else should I do? Thanks for your help.

Comment: `app()->setLocale()` only sets the locale for the current request. Once the page is refreshed, it will return to English. Do you have some kind of Middleware setup to set the locale from something like a Cookie/Session/Browser language setting? Then it will persist to all requests.

Comment: If you intend to define `fr` as the default language, update `locale` in `config/app` to your language.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. I will do  as Tim says. I want a mult-language site.